# Mutate by condition with many columns with each one a different setting

Tags: r, conditional-statements, dplyr

I have looking for but not found how make a simple if for many columns in dplyr.

I have this code (it works):

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
data("PlantGrowth")
PlantGrowth %>% mutate (
  a=if_else(group=="ctrl", weight*2, weight*100),
  b=if_else(group=="ctrl", weight*1,5, weight/100),
  c=if_else(group=="ctrl", weight*4, weight*100),
  d=if_else(group=="ctrl", weight*5, weight/1000)
)
```

And I would like to not repeat the condition. Something like that:

```
PlantGrowth %>% mutate_if_foo (
  group=="ctrl",{
   a=weight*2,
   b=weight*1,5,
   c=weight*4,
   d=weight*5
  }
)%>% mutate_if_foo (
  group!="ctrl",{
   a=weight*100,
   b=weight/100),
   c=weight*100),
   d=weight/1000)
  }
)
```

I've found many answers on `mutate_if`,`mutate_all`,  `mutate_at` , `case_when` but they don't answer at my question.

Please with dplyr / tidyverse.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I've tried, from @Rohit_das  idea about functions.

```
mtcars %>% ( function(df) { 
  if (df$am==1){
    df%>% mutate(
      a=df$mpg*3,
      b=df$cyl*10) 
   }else{ 
     df%>% mutate(
      a=df$disp*300,
      d=df$cyl*1000) 
   }
})
```

but I have Warning message:

```
In if (df$am == 1) { : 
the condition has length > 1 
and only the first element will be used
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the issue here. If you just want to reduce the verbosity of the code then just create a custom function

```
customif = function(x,y) { 
   if_else(group=="ctrl", weight*x, weight*y)
}
```

then you can call this function in your mutate as

```
PlantGrowth %>% mutate (
  a=customif(2,100),
  b=customif(1,5, 1/100),
  c=customif(4, 100),
  d=customif(5, 1/1000)
)
```

Comment: Custom function could be a solution, thanks for this example, but your solution is not what I am looking for. I've taken simple operation but in reality it could be more complex and not between the same n-upplet. I am looking for distribute each different condition one time only by condition, and perhaps distribute your custom function, one time only by condition. In procedural it's possible but I'm looking for dplyr flow solution: maybe it's not made for that, like in SQL. It's true : only to reduce the verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a neat solution with purrr. It takes a data frame of inputs and then dynamically names new columns `a:d` with new inputs for each column. First column will use `x = 2`, `y = 100` and `z = "a"` and then the next row, and so on. The cool thing with functional programming like this is that it is very easy to scale up.

```
library(tidyverse)

iterate <- tibble(x = c(2, 1.5, 4, 5),
                  y = c(100, 1/100, 100, 1/1000),
                  z = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))

fun <- function(x, y, z) {
  PlantGrowth %>% 
    mutate(!!z := if_else(group == "ctrl", weight * x, weight * y)) %>% 
    select(3)
}

PlantGrowth %>% 
  bind_cols(
    pmap_dfc(iterate, fun)
    ) %>% 
  as_tibble
```

Which gives you the same df:

```
# A tibble: 30 x 6
   weight group     a     b     c     d
    <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1   4.17 ctrl   8.34  6.26  16.7  20.8
 2   5.58 ctrl  11.2   8.37  22.3  27.9
 3   5.18 ctrl  10.4   7.77  20.7  25.9
 4   6.11 ctrl  12.2   9.17  24.4  30.6
 5   4.5  ctrl   9     6.75  18    22.5
```

Comment: It's a beautiful juice of brain, but in this case, it's more complicated than the initial code :p

Comment: @phili_b That is true, for sure! It should only be used when it makes the code easier. If you ever find that you need to do the same logic over more than 4 columns and the code becomes to "long", it helps to keep the mind sane :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found an answer. I tested on `mtcars`. I didn't test yet on my real code.

Comment please if I you think I am wrong in the concept.

The conditions of the filters have to be exclusives else I will take duplicate lines.

```
        library(dplyr)
        library(magrittr)
        library(tibble) # only if necessary to preserve rownames
        mtcars %>% ( function(df) { 
                rbind(
                    (df 
                     %>% tibble::rownames_to_column(.) %>%tibble::rowid_to_column(.)  # to preserve rownames
                     %>%dplyr::filter(am==1) 
                     %>%dplyr::mutate(
                        a=mpg*3,
                        b=cyl*10,d=NA)),
                    (df 
                     %>% tibble::rownames_to_column(.) %>%tibble::rowid_to_column(.)  # to preserve rownames
                     %>%dplyr::filter(am!=1) 
                     %>%dplyr::mutate(
                      a=disp*3,
                      d=cyl*100,b=NA))
                )
        })     %>%arrange(rowid)
```